# Post pelo postman está dando erro de Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, mongodb, postman

Percebo que o **FromBody** está vindo null e não sei porque.

Esse é o meu payload no Postman

```
{
    "ChannelCode" : "TS",
    "Name" : "Teste",
    "Celphone" : "(11)999999999",
    "Endpoint" : "www.teste.com.br",
    "TokenLogin" : "1234567890",
    "TokenLoginExpiration" : "2018-06-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Active" : "true"
}
```

Nessa controller eu recebo a request

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize("Bearer")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]ChannelCreateRequest channel)
{
     if (channel == null) throw new WhatsAppApiException("Favor informar os dados do Canal!");
     var result = await _channelCreateService.Process(new ChannelCreateCommand(channel.ChannelCode, channel.Name, 
                             channel.Celphone, channel.Endpoint, 
                             channel.TokenLogin,                                          
                             channel.TokenLoginExpiration ,                                                              
                             channel.Active.GetValueOrDefault(true)));

        return Ok(new ApiReturnItem<ChannelResult> { Item = result, Success = true });
    }
```

tudo será gravado no MongoDB

Classe ChannelCreateRequest

```
public class ChannelCreateRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("codigo_canal")]
        public string ChannelCode { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("nome")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("celular")]
        public string Celphone { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string Endpoint { get; set; }      

        //------ Remover-----------

        [JsonProperty("token_canal")]
        public string TokenLogin { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("token_canal_expiracao")]
        public DateTime? TokenLoginExpiration { get; set; }

       //--------Fim remover---------

        [JsonProperty("ativo")]
        public Boolean? Active { get; set; }
    }
```

respondendo ao Pagotti, eis o postman

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Geralmente isso ocorre quando ele não consegue Parsear a mensagem do corpo para o objeto "ChannelCreateRequest".

Comment: Pode adicionar o código da classe: ChannelCreateRequest?

Comment: @Reiksiel, adicionado

Comment: Você debugou o código pra ver qual ponto a exceção está sendo lançada?

Comment: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**. Todos os campos no FromBody estão null. Ou seja, não recebo nada na request.

Comment: Seu `Request` vem com o `content-type` correto para informar que é um `json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remova as anotações "JsonProperty" parece que a WebApi usa o Newtonsoft como padrão para desserializar a classe e isso está fazendo com que ele se perca.

Outra solução é usar o xml dessa forma:

```
{
    "codigo_canal" : "TS",
    "nome" : "Teste",
    "celular" : "(11)999999999",
    "url" : "www.teste.com.br",
    "token_canal" : "1234567890",
    "token_canal_expiracao" : "2018-06-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ativo" : "true"
}
```

Comment: Em realidade o nome das propriedades no documento do Mongo, deveria ser a que o json serializa e não o nome real delas. Por isso vinha NULL, ele não conhecia aquelas propriedades. Valeu a todos.